# How to detect which of my server IPs DDoS attack is directed at?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, ddos

I have a dedicated server with Windows Server 2008 R2. I have more than 10 IPs assigned. My usual load is under 5%. Sometimes I experience DDoS attacks, my traffic goes up to 30%-50%, then I lose connection to my server. I use Remote Desktop to access the server.

By the nature of my server's activity, the attacker is most likely targeting only one if my IPs. What is the fastest way to find out which of my server IPs is targeted? I tried using Process Hacker 2, but it wasn't helpful. After knowing the IP I can null-route it using my ISP's web interface.

Comment: Packet cap? Examine output of ss?

Comment: I use Windows Server 2008 as OS.

Comment: Tools exist for windows to do the same thing.